# Linux process API using C# in Mono

Tags: c#, linux, process, mono

I know it is possible to code C# .NET apps in Linux using Mono. However, I am wondering about the process interfaces of Linux. Could I use services like `getpid()`, `getppid()` and `fork()` using C# and Mono and running on a Linux environment?

Comment: Do you really need to spawn new system processes, or is it enough to have managed threads inside the Mono VM?

Answer (score 2):

For `getpid()` and `getppid()` you could use [Syscall](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/Mono.Posix/Mono.Posix/Syscall.cs) in this way:

```
using System;
using Mono.Unix.Native;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int pid = Syscall.getpid();
            int ppid = Syscall.getppid();

            Console.WriteLine ("PID: {0}", pid);
            Console.WriteLine ("PPID: {0}", ppid);
        }
    }
}
```

You need `Mono.Posix.dll`

For `fork()` you can use [Process](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Diagnostics/Process.cs). See example here: [creating child process with C#](https://github.com/gumartinm/CSharpForFun/tree/master/Allgemeines/ProcessLauncher)

Documentation about [Process Class C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).